# Indexing and Accessing elements in a List? Or do I need to cut/substring each element string?

Tags: apex

This may seem like a silly question at first... But it is a bit more complex

This is my code:

```
List<Case> cases = [SELECT CaseNumber, AccountId, Status, Subject FROM Case Limit 2]; System.debug(cases);
```

This is what the Execute Anonymous Window printed out

> [3]|DEBUG|(**Case**:{CaseNumber=00001000,
>   AccountId=0011I0000036jdJQAQ, Status=Closed, Subject=Starting
>   generator after electrical failure, Id=5001I000001Mf82QAC},
>   **Case**:{CaseNumber=00001001, AccountId=0011I0000036jdOQAQ, Status=Closed, Subject=Performance inadequate for second consecutive
>   week, Id=5001I000001Mf83QAC})

I would expect the first bolded `Case` is index `0` and the second bolded `Case` is index `1`. However, how do I access the `CaseNumber`, `AccountID`, `Status` and `Subject`?

Do I need to splice out the substring? Or is there a way to access this fields directly? If it needs a substring, is there a substring function in Apex? Or is there is a better method to solve this issue that does not involve substrings?

Comment: You'll want to read more about [Collections](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections.htm) and their related topics, as there's a lot of nifty stuff you can do with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how SOjbects are printed in the logs. `cases` is a `List<SObject>`, so when you debug the value of the list, it prints string representations of the SObject values to produce something readable - the actual list values remain Case records.  You can use [] to index the list at a given position to retrieve one of the records in the list, for example:

`cases[0]` would be the actual Case record, so:

`cases[0].Subject` would be "Starting generator after electrical failure"

`cases[1].Status` would be "Closed"

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian!! It worked! Glad I did not have to write a fancy method!